# Animation on Button - ButtonText stretch

Tags: android, animation, scale, android-button

I have 2 buttons in a `linearlayout`. One Button has `weight=2` and the other one `weight=1`. Now I want to change these. So the first button shrinks to `weight=1` and the second one grow up to `weight = 2`.

I tried it with a `ScaleAnimation` and with an `ObjectAnimator`. Both options works, but I have one problem:

The description of the button will grow up or shrink too. So after the animation the text looks very stretched. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Is it the width you are changing?

Comment: yes :) is there any option, which prevent this?

Comment: Please can you add your XMl animation code?